# Re-enable Microsoft Teams on startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, microsoft-teams

So, Microsoft Teams got installed on my laptop and opened on every start. It annoyed me, so I searched for how to disable that and disabled it.

That was almost a year ago - so, unfortunately I don't remember the method I used to disable it. Now, my team has actually started using Microsoft Teams extensively to the point I need notifications from it, and I really need it to start on boot.

I went to Settings -> Apps -> Startup and it doesn't even appear in the list now. I re-installed teams and that did not work. Then, I searched for teams.exe, and I found the .exe for teams in my profile %appdata%\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current folder and added a shortcut for it to the start menu startup folder, but it is still not starting up on boot.

How do I re-enable it opening on boot?

Answer (score 7):

> How do I re-enable it opening on boot?

You need to make sure the program is configured to automatically startup.  You can enable startup `Microsoft Teams` entry by hitting the **Enable** button.

[image]

If it's configured to automatically startup, and it's not doing that, then the `Task Manager -> Startup` entry likely has been disabled.

[image]

If that entry is enabled, and the application is configured to automatically startup, then you should contact your system Administrator for assistance.  You might also be able to enable it by using [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) as an Administrator.

Answer (score 6):

Disable on startup for current user:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TeamsStartupTask" /v State /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TeamsStartupTask" /v UserEnabledStartupOnce /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

OR

Enable on startup for current user:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\SystemAppData\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TeamsStartupTask" /v State /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

*Teams for home* and *Teams for work or school* have different key names in the registry.

So, if you are using Teams for work version, then you might need to replace:

1. `MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe` with `MSTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
2. `TeamsStartupTask` with `TeamsTfwStartupTask`

Verified on Win11 22H2

Comment: Win11 default install adds consumer version of teams, which this answer addresses

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, the "Settings" page contains "Startup apps", which I can configure, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

At the top-right, there is the possibility to add apps to this list of startup apps.