# How to stop Microsoft Teams from automated start at Windows startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, microsoft-teams

I installed Microsoft Teams just for one meeting. Now it opens at every Windows boot-up. I do not want to uninstall it, I just want it to open when I need it again.

I found out that the Microsoft Teams start at startup on Windows cannot be avoided in the settings (up to now, 09/2021). Even if you uncheck the right box so that it should not start, it seems not to obey the settings. See the list of user comments at
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/how-to-prevent-teams-from-auto-launch/m-p/727148 and its links, saying, that avoiding the start seems impossible up to now. Scripts do not seem to be able to reach the goal either. I tried the [PowerShell script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/scripts/powershell-script-teams-reset-autostart) that is linked by [Use Group Policy to prevent Microsoft Teams from starting automatically after installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/teams-install#use-group-policy-to-prevent-microsoft-teams-from-starting-automatically-after-installation), to no avail.

How to stop Microsoft Teams from automated start at Windows startup?

Comment: Try the PowerShell script in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/configuring_startup_settings_in_microsoft_teams_with_windows_powershell/).

Comment: @harrymc I will not test it since it is solved for me. I also fear that running that script might lead to problems if you want to undo the script perhaps, at least I see some risk of that after reading [Re-enable Microsoft Teams on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1537229/re-enable-microsoft-teams-on-startup?rq=1). Someone else may kindly check this and comment whether the script works. Then it could be another answer.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1537229/re-enable-microsoft-teams-on-startup/1537241#1537241) answer still applies to my system that is running the current version of Microsoft Teams.

Comment: @Ramhound I took the idea from the link in your comment, your answer was the reason to find the solution here. My problem was the other way round, that is, how to disable the startup, therefore I opened a new question.

Comment: @questionto42 - Yeah…All you do is disable the option, I tested that the option still works, before I submitted my comment. The accepted answer to this question just repeats information from the accepted answer from what i believe is a duplicate question. Others will have to flag since I won’t flag it myself since that WILL close the question (even though I truly believe) my answer to that duplicate applies to this question. You said it cannot be disabled but it obviously can, if your accepted solution, disables the startup entry.

Comment: @Ramhound I have read the comments of the users of the link in the question, and I searched further, without finding any user to confirm that disabling is possible at all. It is not my opinion, it is the result of my research. I invested too much time on the links in question before I found your worthful and simple answer on the opposite problem [Re-enable Microsoft Teams on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1537229/re-enable-microsoft-teams-on-startup) (which you would not search for, normally). I will flag it as a duplicate since it is your idea that helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ctrl**+ **Shift** + **Escape**(Esc) to open Task manager

[Here you click on Startup to view startup apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8slD.png)

[Click on Microsoft teams from the list of apps, the on your bottom right corner click Disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJPIy.png)

Comment: I had forgotten about that shortcut. And good to have the screenshots in English.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Task Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>,
click "Startup", right-click the program you want to enable/disable from opening when the computer starts up, and click "Disable". 
In my case, I had two entries for Microsoft Teams in the list.

I only needed to deactivate the one with the known icon to stop it from starting at Windows startup:

[image: Task Manager window, in German, with "Autostart" ("Startup") tab active, showing entries for "Microsoft Teams"]

If that does not work for you, deactivate both.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Screenshot isn’t in English