# Windows 11: Never-used application hogging up memory

Tags: memory, performance, microsoft-teams, windows-11

`Windows 11`

On my recently-purchased laptop (yesterday, in fact), Microsoft Teams — a totally unused application on my system (have never even opened it, and have no need of it) — seems to topping the charts for memory usage. Any ideas why that might be, and thoughts on what I should do? Or am I worrying too much and a 25% memory usage is OK for a brand-new PC?

[image]

[PS: Before you call me an overconcerned parent, I'd like to tell you that I'm going to great lengths to prevent my new PC from going slow & unusable like my old one. ;-)]

Answer (score 1):

This is not abnormal. Teams is written using similar code to Google Chrome as I understand it, and uses similarly large amounts of memory.

If you don't require it, you should be able to uninstall it by right-clicking on its Start Menu entry or in Apps and Features, or you can disable its startup using Task Manager.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. May I please know how exactly I could disable its startup? I don't want to uninstall it (Teams) just yet.

Comment: @Shane I've not used Win11 (I'm on Win8.1 and see no reason to 'upgrade' as yet, it works perfectly well, ain't broke, don't fix it etc) but I would assume that Win11's task manager is the same. How I do it on Win8.1 is: Ctrl+Alt+Del, select Task Manager, Select 'Start-up' tab, identify process and select it, click on 'Disable' button lower right. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @Shane -Just disable the application from automatically starting. It’s in the options [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1537229/re-enable-microsoft-teams-on-startup/1537241#1537241). You can also just uninstall it then reinstall it when you want to use it